# Handshaking with Octopus server fails from a TeamCity agent

Tags: certificate, teamcity, octopus-deploy, handshaking

We've been successfully using TeamCity and Octopus on a single machine, and now we have added a new build agent due to growing number of simultaneous builds. I have set up a new Octopus Tentacle and verified that Tentacle is reachable from the Octopus server in Listener role. However,any build that uses Octopack fails when executed on the new TeamCity agent. Here is an extract from the build log:

> Running command: octo.exe create-release --server
>   servername:8443 --apikey SECRET --project NRK Bridge (Legacy)
>   --enableservicemessages --version 0.0.0.662 --deployto Dev --waitfordeployment --package=NRK.Bridge.Web:0.0.0.662 --packageversion=0.0.0.662 
>   [12:06:02]Creating Octopus Deploy release 
>   [12:06:02]Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version 2.0.8.22
>   [12:06:03]Handshaking with Octopus server: servername:8443 
>   [12:06:06]The following certificate errors were
>   encountered when establishing the HTTPS connection to the server:
>   RemoteCertificateChainErrors 
>   [12:06:06]Certificate subject name: CN=servername 
>   [12:06:06]Certificate thumbprint: 79C26(...)
>   [12:06:07]The following certificate errors were encountered when
>   establishing the HTTPS connection to the server:
>   RemoteCertificateChainErrors 
>   [12:06:07]Certificate subject name: CN=servername 
>   [12:06:07]Certificate thumbprint: 79C26(...)
>   [12:06:08]The following certificate errors were encountered when
>   establishing the HTTPS connection to the server:
>   RemoteCertificateChainErrors

What I noticed is that the certificate thumbprint in the build log is different from thumbprints shown in Octopus server machine page. I tried to generate a new API key and re-register a Tentacle. Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have a similar issue

Comment: In the end it worked. Must have been API key issue. Don't remember what we did exactly to fix the keys.

Comment: Here we received this error message when we were using a self signed SSL certificate for the Octopus Deploy website. Solved it by adding the certificate to Trusted Root Certificate Authorities for Local Machine. We had to do this on all servers that are running TeamCity build agents, including the local machine which is running both TeamCity and Octopus Deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy the Api key into Team City? The api key is different to thumb prints. Api Key can be found in Octopus Admin section, under users tab.